# Perl attempt to read line from filehandle without blocking

Tags: perl

I am writing a simple utility that tests the round trip time to a few hosts and picks the one that's fastest on average. However, doing this serially instead of in parallel takes a while, so I am spawning one ping process per host and reading from them. For my use case the `scalar <$fh>` operation which blocks until the line is read is good enough, since I can't avoid waiting until the slowest host times out. But if I want to get just the fastest *k* hosts and don't care about the rest this is a bad approach. Is there a way to attempt to read a complete line with a certain time limit, and fail without consuming any bytes if the time limit passes?

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

# generate command to get average 
# round trip length to hostname.
# we know in advance that each command only
# emits one line
sub command {
    my $host = shift;
    qq(ping -w 1 -c 5 '$host' |) . 
    q(tail -n 1 |) .
    q(sed 's/^.*= //;s/ ms//' |) .
    q(awk -F '/' 'END {print $2}');
}

# launch each ping in its own process and create
# a filehandle that reads from it
sub filehandles {
    my @handles;
    for my $command (@_) {
        open my $fh, '-|', $command or
        die "cannot open file ($!) associated with $command";
    push @handles, $fh;
    }
    @handles;
}

my @commands = map command($_), qw[google.com cnn.com wikipedia.org];
my @fhs = filehandles(@commands);

# read line from each of the ping processes sequentially
for my $fh (@fhs) {
    my $line = scalar <$fh>;
    chomp $line;
    printf "%s\n", $line || '+INF';
}
```

Comment: Do you know Net::Ping http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/Ping.html, i do not know if it has hires timeouts but it has timeouts..

Comment: I did not. Thanks. It does still look like if I want to do multiple pings in parallel or concurrently using this module, I'd have to use multiple processes.

Comment: You can call `select` ( select-RBITS,WBITS,EBITS,TIMEOUT ) or `IO::Select` ( http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html ).  To get the fastest k responses, call it in a loop and keep track of how many responses you've gotten each time through.

Comment: Using `Net::Ping` with threads or `Parallel::ForkManager` would work well actually.

Comment: @MaxLybbert how do you keep track of which handle is which when using IO::Select? In the original example I am relying on each handles position in the array to identify which host the output is associated with. Edit: Evidently I can just use a refhash.

Comment: I'd be thinking using `Parallel::ForkManager` and just bail out when you've found the 5 you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might tackle your problem a bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $wait_for = 3; #wait for first 3
my @host_list = qw ( server1 server2 server3 server4 ); 

my %host_for; 

foreach my $host ( @host_list ) {
   my $pid = fork; 
   if ( $pid ) { 
       $host_for{$pid} = $host;
   } 
   else {
       my $result = `ping -w 1 -c 5 $host`; 
       last; #so we don't fork bomb 
   }
}

for ( 1..$wait_for ) {
   my $return_pid  = waitpid ( -1, 0 );
   print "Process $return_pid for $host_for{$return_pid} returned\n"; 
}

$SIG{'CHLD'} = 'IGNORE'; #we no longer care about return codes of any still running forks.
```

There's probably a bit of optimisation there still - I suspect you can use an `exec` to reduce process overhead when forked, rather than using backticks. 
(or Net::Ping)

But the idea is hopefully clear - fork a bunch of times, reap N forks, and then match their pids up with a hash to do your IPC, rather than having to worry about passing back return codes. Although you should probably check the return code of the fork, just to make sure the ping didn't fail entirely.

Waitpid will give you $? which will allow you to test success.